# Left and Right Scrolling in Image

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

i want to display large image in small control such that entire image can be scrolled. 
for this, i have used following code but i could only succeed in achieving vertical scrolling. 
what should i do for enabling both, horizontal and vertical scrolling ?

```
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Width="470">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="470" Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Name="drag" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

if there is any other solution than using scrollviewer then please share it, or mention any changes in this code which are useful for achieving the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Width="470">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="470" Height="270" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Name="drag" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

You need to set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility` properties to achieve desired scrolling.

**Edit :**

If you want to see the scroll bars always you can set   `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" and VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`  .Otherwise("Auto") scroll bars will appear based on the content size

Comment: this works correctly, but not if i give height and width to an image control.

Comment: You want scrollbars visible always ?  You can set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility  apropriately

Comment: i am not bothered about visibility of scrollbars, what my concern is, the image should be scrollable. your solution works like a charm but only if we do not set height and width of an image control.

Comment: Try by setting height and width bigger than scroll viewer's height and width . Scrollviewer is used when actual content is more than the viewport.

Comment: i tried, but what happened is, i was only able to scroll area which is exceeding scrollviewer, not entire image.